# wsdl2java generates null pointer exception apache cxf

Tags: cxf, soap-client, wsdl2java

[stacktrace of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeWlY.png)

While generating the java client from the wsdl I am getting the above error.
I have used the binding file to solve the duplicate name errors and missing schema declaration errors

```
gradle task 
cxf version is 3.0.0
task wsdl2java3(type: JavaExec) {
    ext {
         outputDir = file("$jaxbOutputDir")
    }   
    systemProperties  = ['javax.xml.accessExternalSchema': 'file' , 'file.encoding':'UTF8']
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    outputs.dir outputDir
    main = 'org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava'
    classpath = project.configurations.cxf
    args '-d', outputDir
    ar`enter code here`gs '-client'
    args '-verbose'
    args '-mark-generated'
    args '-p',"com.niloosoft.directorymanagementservice"
    args "https://hunterdirectory.hunterhrms.com/DirectoryManagementService.svc?wsdl"
    doLast {
         println "----- cxf jaxb2 files generated -----"
    }
}
```

binding file used

```
<jaxb:bindings    
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"   
    jaxb:version="2.0">
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://huntercards.hunterhrms.com/HunterCards.svc?xsd=xsd2" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type" />
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation=" https://huntercards.hunterhrms.com/HunterCards.svc?xsd=xsd13" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type" />
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation=" https://huntercards.hunterhrms.com/HunterCards.svc?xsd=xsd3" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type" />
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple />
  </globalBindings>

  <jaxb:bindings scd="~xsd:complexType">
    <class name="ComplexTypeType"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <jaxb:bindings scd="~xsd:simpleType">
    <class name="SimpleTypeType"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <jaxb:bindings scd="~xsd:group">
    <class name="GroupType"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <jaxb:bindings scd="~xsd:attributeGroup">
    <class name="AttributeGroupType"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <jaxb:bindings scd="~xsd:element">
    <class name="ElementType"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <jaxb:bindings scd="~xsd:attribute">
    <class name="attributeType"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried the latest 3.2.7 version? 3.0.0 is no longer supported.

Comment: Finally issue got fixed upgrading all the dependencies to the latest
@DennisKieselhorst thanks for the reply.